# liquibase databasechangelog doesn't show machine name

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase is a great tool for orchestrating database changes. I'm running liquibase changesets on startup in a cluster environment. First application instance puts a lock (in the databasechangeloglock) table and executes the changesets. Other instances as they grab the lock, just marks the excuted changesets as [MARK_RAN](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html). So far so good.

Recently there was an issue and I had to dive into the details of databasechangelog table. I was expecting to see the instance name (machine name) in the meta information. But I couldn't find it there. Is there a way to customize liquibase behavior so that it writes the instance name to the databasechangelog table as meta information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably have to be a change to Liquibase itself - there isn't anything you can do with configuration. The `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table does have a column `LOCKEDBY` for that purpose, but the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table is designed to not care. If you wanted to keep track of who was running Liquibase when a change was deployed, you would have to do something like what we are doing at [Datical](http://www.datical.com/) - we have custom code that wraps Liquibase. We have a class that listens to events from Liquibase as a deploy happens, and we then write that information to an 'audit' database that keeps track of all that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you!